# Application requirements to write a home manager in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, homescreen

Is there anything (plugin, library etc.), that would allow me to write a start up application / home screen manager for Android, using PhoneGap? If yes, then what particular circumstances must such application met?

Or, as I assume, this isn't possible and a native, Java-based, application for Android must be written to accomplish this?

Comment: Greets to all downvoters and closevoters too lazy and to scared to leave even a tiny comment, what is wrong with this question. Love you! All of you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm sorry to tell you, but my opinion is that

it's IMPOSSIBLE to achieve such goal using Cordova/PhoneGap.

---

Hybrid applications are using smartphone's native [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) , thus you cannot invoke/reach the WebView from the Home/Launcher of the phone.

In order to get such WebView you must be in some sort of application (e.g. hybrid app written by you). The Home/Launcher CAN'T SERVE as WebView therefore you can't make such things with Cordova/PhoneGap

Sorry for killing the hope :D